# vstest.console.exe works, but not with a good file name, CodeCoverage.exe does not give any results

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, mstest

I have the following setup:

```
set __vsTestConsoleExe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe
set __codeCoverageExe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe

set __testFile=My.UnitTests.dll

REM Below I get a ".coverage" file with the correct coverage.  But the file name is kinda-random
"%__vsTestConsoleExe%" "%__testFile%" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage

PAUSE

REM  Below I get a big ole nothing
"%__codeCoverageExe%" collect /output:DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage "%__vsTestConsoleExe%" "%__testFile%" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage 
"%__codeCoverageExe%" analyze /output:DynamicCodeCoverage.coveragexml DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage
```

when the below line runs:

```
"%__vsTestConsoleExe%" "%__testFile%" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage
```

I get a good .coverage file, but its a generated file name like:

```
MyUSERNAME_MYMACHINE 2016-03-24 16_03_20.coverage
```

The lines after the PAUSE statement (in the first code block) looks like they should collect the coverage (and note, I'm giving it the same ' "%__vsTestConsoleExe%" ' comamand .......but I get big nothing from it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get vstest.console.exe to work.

I was able to get a "predictable" file name AND get information in the .coverage file using MsTest.exe.

```
set __msTestExe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
set __codeCoverageExe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe



REM the below calls will create the binary *.coverage files
"%__codeCoverageExe%" collect /output:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\AAA_DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage" "%__msTestExe%" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.One.dll" /resultsfile:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\My.UnitTests.One.trx"
"%__codeCoverageExe%" collect /output:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\BBB_DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage" "%__msTestExe%" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.Two.dll" /resultsfile:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\My.UnitTests.Two.trx"
"%__codeCoverageExe%" collect /output:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\CCC_DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage" "%__msTestExe%" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.Three.dll" /resultsfile:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\My.UnitTests.Three.trx"
```

You can also combine the 3 UnitTests.dlls into one call

```
REM the below calls will create the binary *.coverage file
"%__codeCoverageExe%" collect /output:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\ZZZ_DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage" "%__msTestExe%" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.One.dll" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.Two.dll" /testcontainer:"D:\BuildStuff\BuildResults\My.UnitTests.Three.dll" /resultsfile:"D:\BuildStuff\TestResults\My.UnitTests.AllOfThem.trx"
```

ZZZ_DynamicCodeCoverage.coverage is "predictably" named, and has actual values in the .coverage file.

No idea why the .coverage file(s) created by CodeCoverage.exe .. with the vstest.console.exe in its argument list.... doesn't work.  :(
Again, doesn't work equals . 'Creates the .coverage file, but opening it, it has no info in it".